# "Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://favicon/..." after migrating to manifest V3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, favicon, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm getting the error

`Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://favicon/size/16@1x/https://google.com/`

This happened when I tried to migrate a manifest for a chrome extension from v2 to v3.

I need to fetch favicons for bookmarked links, but unable to load local resource. How do I fix it?

```json
{
   "background": {
      "service_worker": "./src/background.js"
   },
   "action": {
      "default_popup": "./src/popup.html",
      "default_title": "Minimal Homepage"
   },
   "chrome_url_overrides": {
      "newtab": "./src/new-tab-page.html"
   },
   "description": "Minimal new tab page",
   "icons": {
      "128": "src/images/icon/icon_128.png",
      "16": "src/images/icon/icon_16.png",
      "32": "src/images/icon/icon_32.png",
      "48": "src/images/icon/icon_48.png"
   },
   "manifest_version": 3,
   "name": "Minimal Homepage",
   "permissions": [ "bookmarks", "storage", "sessions", "tabs", "favicon" ],
   "web_accessible_resources": [
      {
        "resources": ["_favicon/*"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "extension_ids": ["*"]
      }
    ],
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

```js
    /* append (almost) every tab */
      for (let tab of tabs) {
        let element = el(
          'div.link.truncate',
          el(
            'div.favicon',
            el(
              'img',
              {
                src: `chrome://favicon/size/16@1x/${tab.url}`,
                srcset: `
                  chrome://favicon/size/16@1x/${tab.url},
                  chrome://favicon/size/16@2x/${tab.url} 2x
                `
              }
            )
          ),
          tab.deviceName + ' › ' + tab.title,
          {
            href: '#',
            title: tab.title,
            'data-type': 'shortcut',
            click: () => {
              chrome.sessions.restore(tab.sessionId)
            },
            dragstart: (event) => {
              event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', tab.url)
            }
          }
        )

        if (box.children.length < 5) {
          box.appendChild(element)
        }
      }
```

I've tried following Google documentation about migrating from v2 to v3, but it hasn't worked.

I expect this to fetch favicons for bookmarked links, but I'm unable to load local resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Manifest V3, the way favicons are loaded has changed slightly. There's a full guide for migrating here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/favicon/.

As a TLDR, you'll want to request the `favicon` permission in your manifest. Then, if you need to load the favicons in to non-extension pages, you'll need to expose the URL under `web_accessible_resources` in your manifest:

```json
"web_accessible_resources": [
  {
    "resources": ["_favicon/*"],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "extension_ids": ["*"]
  }
]
```

You should then be able to load favicons as follows:

`chrome-extension://[YOUR_EXTENSION_ID]/_favicon/?pageUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&size=32`

Comment: The problem with this new api is that it often fails to load the favicon even though it is loaded in the bookmarks bar and shows up in tab. Not consistent at all!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @cpakken. We have a bug to track some improvements for those cases here: https://crbug.com/1431958